# Combinations: How many possible codes does she have

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

A spy is trying to open a security door by entering the correct code into a key pad. The
key pad has 10 buttons (for the digits $0,\dots ,9)$. How many possible codes does she have
to try at most if.../

(a) ...she only knows that the correct code is four digits long? I think this is $10!/\binom{10}{4}$.

(b) ...she knows that the correct code consists of four distinct digits?.

(c) ...she knows which four distinct digits are involved in the correct code? I think it will be $4!$ but not sure.

Comment: Please please format your math and sentences, and make it legible. Help us help you.

Comment: Questions that do not use MathJax will likely be downvoted and/or deleted.

Comment: You must thank Aaron for formatting it for you, esp. given you have already been on the site for a while now. Please do it yourself in future. Coming to your answers - c) is correct but a) is wrong. Can you please tell your reasoning for (a)? Note that in (a), digits can repeat.

Comment: a) $10^4$ = all  four digit numbers.  b) $10\times 9\times 8\times 7$

Comment: Thank you! @herbsteinberg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) In this case, the number of possibilities would be $10^4=10000$.

b) In this case, the number would be $P(10,4)=10\times9\times8\times{7}=5040$.

c) In this case, the number would be $4!=4\times3\times2\times1=24$.

Comment: Please do not answer questions that are simply problem statements (PSQs).

Answer (score 2):

a) $10^4$ = all  four digit numbers.  b) $10\times 9\times 8\times 7$ c) $4!$ correct if all digits are different.

Comment: Please do not answer questions that are simply problem statements (PSQs).